# plot failing to update for multiple Pandas hist calls on mac when run one at a time

Tags: python, pandas

Here's some sample code. Surprisingly this bug seems to require running the last line separately from the rest.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = np.nan
a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5.0,n,n,n,n,n,n]
b = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4.0,6,7,8,n,n,n]
d = {'a':a,'b':b}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.b.hist()

#Wait for the plot to come up, then run this line
df.a.hist()
```

On Windows I'm seeing this, as expected:

[image: Hist with correct behavior]

On my Mac I'm seeing this:

[image: Hist with 2nd dataset missing]

If I run all the code at once on my mac, I get the correct behavior.

I currently have this warning message on my mac when I first go to plot:
qt.qpa.drawing: Layer-backing can not be explicitly controlled on 10.14 when built against the 10.14 SDK

I'm using Python 3.9.12, IPython 7.33.0, Matplotlib 3.5.2, Pandas 1.5.3, Mac OS 12.6.3, Spyder 5.3.0, Automatic graphics backend, Qt 5.12.9 | PyQt5 5.12.3 | Darwin 21.6.0

Changed backend to Tkinter and warning is now gone but plot error remains.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Matplotlib to the latest version, currently 3.7.1 and that fixed the problem. I switched the backend back to Automatic (from Tkinter) and now I am still getting the layer-backing warning but the plot is rendering fine ...

For Spyder with Anaconda, if you go to Environments tab in Anaconda (below Home), click on the green play button next to your current environment, and the click on `Open Terminal` a terminal will pop up.

[image]

Run:
`pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

Once this has finished close the console in Spyder (should open a new one). I had to do this twice as the first time I ran it I got strange warnings (errors?). Or you could probably restart Spyder as well ....